# Find most used values from several columns and rows

Tags: mysql

How can I find the most used values (in this case, integers) from several columns and rows of the same table?

I'm building a fantasy football game and I want to get the most used players every week from the users lineups (columns player1 to player11 in the following image):

[image]

Comment: You should consider in changing your current design. Having a column to each player in the same table is not good. You should have a player table associated with your user table. That way you wouldn't need those eleven columns on the user table.

Comment: I know, and that was my initial approach, but I had to change it with this design because it's way more efficient than having 11 rows for each lineup, each one with the lineup_id and player_id columns

Comment: well if your going to leave the table like that what i would do is create a stored procedure. in there create a temporary table with a column player id then select each of the player(1-11) columns into the table. then you can go you select on the temp table and get the data you need. but like Jorge Campos said, you really should change the design of how it works.

Comment: I'll try your temp table approach. Regarding the design, the initial was the one Jorge Campos suggested, but it isn't good in terms of performance: the database should store 3 fields (lineup_id, position, player_id) + indexes instead of just playerN, and every lineup read has to join 11 rows from other table. I had to change it when the number of users growth.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- create a temporary table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE game_player (
    player_id INT NOT NULL,
    game_date DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (player_id, game_date)
);

-- populate the table for player1-11
INSERT INTO game_player
SELECT player1, STR_TO_DATE(`day`, '%Y%m%d') FROM YOURTABLE;
INSERT INTO game_player
SELECT player2, STR_TO_DATE(`day`, '%Y%m%d') FROM YOURTABLE;
...
INSERT INTO game_player
SELECT player11, STR_TO_DATE(`day`, '%Y%m%d') FROM YOURTABLE;

-- view player_id and the date he played - the data you populated
SELECT * FROM game_player;

-- GROUP_CONCAT(game_date) to see what days they played (NOT REQUIRED)
-- most-used player with #games
SELECT player_id, COUNT(*) games, GROUP_CONCAT(game_date) game_dates
FROM test.game_player
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY games DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have until now, although is super slow (200s for ~1M records):

```
SELECT player, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM (
SELECT player1 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player2 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player3 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player4 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player5 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player6 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player7 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player8 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player9 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player10 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player11 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player12 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player13 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player14 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
UNION ALL
SELECT player15 AS `player` FROM `lineup` WHERE `lineup`.`day` = 2015026
) AS matchDayPlayers GROUP BY player ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```